# nginx virtual hosting wildcards

Tags: nginx

I have one ip number to use, 1.2.3.4 and want to share it with several domains.  I have site1.com separate, but the other domains I have a script to display content based on the domain.  I've moved to a new server, and I'm using nginx 1.0.6.  This worked as desired on the old server with nginx 0.8.54.  The problem is all domain names pointed at 1.2.3.4 are always showing site.com (the first server block) instead of falling to the wildcard server block.  How can I modify this to work as desired?

```
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /home/www/site.com;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 1.2.3.4;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either move your fallback `server` block above the block with specific domains, or change your `listen` to `listen 1.2.3.4 default_server;`.